Interchange of double limit
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N,\,N\geq 2$ be a bounded domain and $0<s<1$. Moreover $H^s(\Omega)$ is the fractional Sobolev space defined by
$$
H^s(\Omega)=\{v:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\text{ measurable }: v\in L^2(\Omega),\,\frac{v(x)-v(y)}{|x-y|^\frac{N+2s}{2}}\in L^2(\Omega\times\Omega)\}.
$$
The space
$$H^s_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)=\{v:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\text{ measurable }: v\in H^s(K)\quad \forall K\Subset\Omega\}.
$$
The space $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is defined similarly and we define the space
$$H^s_{0}(\Omega)=\{v\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^N): v=0\text{ in }\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega\}.
$$
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\delta>1$ and $\{u_n\}\in H^s_{0}(\Omega)\cap L^1(\Omega)$ is uniformly bounded in $H^s_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ such that $T_k(u_n)^\frac{\delta+1}{2}\in H_0^{s}(\Omega)$ for every $k>0$ and there exists a constant $c>0$ depending only on $\omega$ such that for every $n$, $u_n\geq c>0$ in $\omega$ for every $\omega\Subset\Omega$. Here $T_k(u)=\min\{k,u\}$.
Let $u_n\to u$ weakly in $H^s_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$. Then is it true that for every $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega$),
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{(u_n(x)-u_n(y))(\phi(x)-\phi(y))}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}\, dx dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{(u(x)-u(y))(\phi(x)-\phi(y))}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}\, dx dy.
$$
My approach is the following:
Using the conditions on $T_k$ and using Theorem 3.6 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00056, we get
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{(T_k(u_n(x))-T_k(u_n(y)))(\phi(x)-\phi(y))}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}\, dx dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{(u_n(x)-u_n(y))(\phi(x)-\phi(y))}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}\, dx dy.
$$
Therefore, we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{(u_n(x)-u_n(y))(\phi(x)-\phi(y))}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}\, dx dy=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{(T_k(u_n(x))-T_k(u_n(y)))(\phi(x)-\phi(y))}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}\, dx dy.
$$
So my question is can we interchange the above limits? That is,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{(T_k(u_n(x))-T_k(u_n(y)))(\phi(x)-\phi(y))}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}\, dx dy=\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{(T_k(u_n(x))-T_k(u_n(y)))(\phi(x)-\phi(y))}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}\, dx dy.
$$
Many thanks in advance.

What is $T_k$? Also you do not want to let $n \to \infty$ in $\int_{\mathbb R^n}$.

Thank you. I added $T_k(u)=\min{k,u}$.

I am sorry for the confusions. I changed $n$ to $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$. But yes, by the weak convergence of $T_k(u_n)$, I can put the limit as $n\to\infty$ inside the double integral. My main concern is to interchange the limits as mentioned.
